# postgres full text search and spring-data hibernate

Tags: postgresql, spring-data

I have a table with the following columns:

id,
url,
content

So there are lots of records with url, content where to search, etc

I need to write a query in postgres 9.5 which takes my custom search string like

'I want to search bla bla' and search for all possible entries in 'content' column, and then return ids of records where it found matches. May I use for it sth like

```
SELECT to_tsvector('fat cats ate fat rats') @@ to_tsquery('fat & rat');
```

or is there any more advanced tool for this? Also, how to gracefuly integrate it with spring-data? Thanks

Comment: hi did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

On the below part of the question,
"gracefuly integrate it with spring-data"

You can use [Spring Data Custom repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) to implement custom queries and still have them accessed & executed via standard Spring data interface.

Thanks